# How to send data from an activity to php and to retrieve data from same php into another activity?

Tags: php, android

From the first image In my two of the activities I am sending request 
      to php two different 
      php files and I am getting valid response to android activities.

[image: Image 1]

In  the second image , On combining the above both php files into one 
     php file , when sending request from Activity 1 to php, I am not able 
     to 
     getting response and for activity 2 also.

[image: Image 2]

```
 private void login(final String textViewNameq, String textViewNameqw,String day) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];
            String day=params[2];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("day", day));
            String result = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "Your php link goes here");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

and My php code goes here,

```
   <?php
include("my php file path");                        
//  if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $Fromname = trim($_POST['username']);
        $Toname = trim($_POST['password']);
        //$Fromdate=$_POST['iddate'];
        //$Fromd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Fromdate));
        $from_id=trim($_POST['idss']);
        $to_id=trim($_POST['iddd']);
    //  }

     $url="http://my url with API key goes here";


     $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');                
            $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);                 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                        
                $page = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);    
                $result=json_decode($page,true);     
                if(empty($result)){                 
                    $page=file_get_contents($url);
                    $result=json_decode($page,true);
                }
```

Comment: You added a PHP tag, this code doesn't reference any need of PHP code. Please edit your tag to the programming language you're using if you want help, only PHP programmers will see this.

Comment: show your php script

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the required response from the same php file. All you need to do is send the required information in your request method and process accordingly in the php file and generate the response. We can help help u better if u show ur Php Script

Comment: yes @ Ratul Doley I have added My php script above.

Comment: If the above code is ur full code, then it clearly generates no response i.e it prints nothing for ur app to read... If $result is what u want to read as response then write `if(!empty($result))  echo $result; else //some response`

Comment: If I echo $ result , I can get the response if there are two php files like in the first image, but not for single php file like in the second image.

Comment: What do u mean two php files? A request from any activity will get the response if the parameters of the request are ok. If u want sepecific response for each activity then send a flag in ur reuqest and generate the response accordingly.....

Comment: I have used intent to send the value from first activity and also retrieving value in second activity from php. I Got my answer , Thank you all.